# Python: Combining 'complex' functions; one has oswalk other writes to file/database

Tags: python, function, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I have read numerous examples of combining functions in a main function, or calling them after both are defined, but all of the examples are very simple, and are not easily applied to what I am trying to do.

I will paste in the code so far.  Please note that the second function here is shortened for the sake of making a quick print statement/checking if the files are being passed correctly by writing to an outfile.  In the full second function, the value of 'n2' is actually intended to be entered into a SQlite3 database, such that I can identify which entries in the table are from a given file.

When I call these functions below individually, such as in the code below, I get a list of names from the first function, but

< function fastq2SQlite at 0x0000000011CD7208 >

for the second, and no file is created as specified in the function.

Thank you for your assistance.

```
import os
import fnmatch

def findFiles (path, filter):
    files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return files

def fastq2SQlite(files):
    nmlst = []
    out = ('path.txt', 'w')
    for f in files:
        names = f.split('\\')
        continue
    for name in names:
        n = name.split('.')
        n2 = n[0]
        nmlst.append(n2)
    out.write(n2)
    out.close()
    return n2

print findFiles('path', 'filter')
print fastq2SQlite()
```

Comment: Have you forgot to pass `files` into your function `fastq2SQlite()`?

Comment: You'd probably want to do `print fastq2SQlite(findFiles('path', 'filter'))` if I understand it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't passed **files** parameter into **fastq2SQlite()** function, try this:

```
print fastq2SQlite(findFiles('path', 'filter'))
```

And you'd probably thought after running your first function **findFiles**, the **files** will be automatically passed to second function, it is not working like this.

**files** in **findFiles** is a local namespace which isn't accessible from outside your function. And for your second function to work, you still need to pass the parameter **files** to it.

The strange behaviour you had was because you were trying to print a function without **()**, like this:

```
print fastq2SQlite
<function fastq2SQlite at 0x111917230>
```

And to actually call the function you need to add **(whatever parameter you need to pass)**, in your case i believe is this: `fastq2SQlite(findFiles('path', 'filter'))`, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One of your bugs is in this function:

```
def findFiles (path, filter):
    files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return files
```

You're using the identifier `files` twice: not just as the identifier for the list you're initializing to `[]`, appending to, and eventually returning, but **also** as a loop variable in the `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):` so it's being re-bound to a different list each time through the loop.  Rename one of the two uses, e.g to

```
def findFiles (path, filter):
    all_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            all_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return all_files
```

to fix this one error.  Another error is that in:

```
print findFiles('path', 'filter')
print fastq2SQlite()
```

you're just printing the list of files, **not** passing it on to `fastq2SQlite`.  To fix this one, change the code e.g to:

```
all_files = findFiles('path', 'filter')
print all_files
print fastq2SQlite(all_files)
```

Moreover, in `fastq2SQlite`, you assign `out` a tuple:

```
out = ('path.txt', 'w')
```

but then later you call `out.write`, which makes no sense.  Maybe you meant

```
out = open('path.txt', 'w')
```

Further, in the `for f in files:` loop, the `continue` at the end of the loop is useless and redundant (though at least, differently from the other bugs, innocuous:-).

There may be other bugs yet, but even my "debugger eyes" are exhausted after finding three major ones in such a tiny compass...:-)

Comment: Thanks...I edited out the open command when I edited the 'out' file line (seemed silly to include the path and file info).   I will try suggestions for the other and and see what happens.